# Reduce Google Maps Costing and only call google maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

As everyone of us know that google maps platform has introduced new pricing model, i'm trying my best to reduce the cost of google maps service as much as possible by disabling the stuff that i'm not using on my website which is using maps service.

Here is the screenshot of last three days of costing of my google maps service as we're managing high traffic website, i think we're going to spend a lot of money on maps service.

[image]

Also i'm loading google map onto the screen only when needed and then i'm calling this function to initialise maps:

```
find_centre_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("find-centre-map"), {
    center: {lat: -28.214739, lng: 134.657340}
    , zoom: 5
    , mapTypeControl: false
    , gestureHandling: 'greedy'
    , styles: [{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]}]
    , zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    }
    , streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    }
});
```

After this i'm using a static json file which conatins lat,lng and marker info and loop it to show markers on google map.

Can anyone please explain me how can i disable Maps and Street View API - Dynamic maps service??

And just use Maps javascript API which is free. Check above screenshot to see map serivce usage and it's SKU pricing.

Any help to reduce map costs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I am not good at English, so I'm sorry in the machine translation sentences.

I am suffering from the same problem. However, I will tell you that I was able to reduce many charges for the time being. It is to turn off Street View.

```js
find_centre_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("find-centre-map"), {
    center: {lat: -28.214739, lng: 134.657340}
    , zoom: 5
    , mapTypeControl: false
    , streetview : false
    , gestureHandling: 'greedy'
    , styles: [{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]}]
    , zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    }
});
```